# How to calculate the maximum number of iterations taken by perceptron learning algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I believe perceptron learning algorithm has an upper bound on the number of iterations it takes to converge for a linear separable data. I looked to find the exact formula that would help me find out the number of iterations this would take, but it was not there on wikipedia.

I read online that this entity depends on the number of data samples, so if I have n(say 5000) samples, how many iterations will it take for perceptron to converge(assume that the data is linearly separable). Or is it not as straightforward and depends on the data itself?

P.S. Very new to machine learning, hence a simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) refers to a proof by *Novikoff, A. B. (1962)*, one of the early results in statistical-learning.

Here some slightly different form given a result for the online-learning environment:

When `||x_i|| ≤ D for all i` (intuition: radius of the training instances) and a `margin >= γ`:

- iterations needed are bounded above by: `(D/γ)^2`.

Interesting consequences:

- convergence-result independent on number of samples!
- convergence-result independent on input-dimension!

Comment: x_i is probably the datasample, but what is D? and also what is y(is it the class or output to which our datasets are to be classified like maybe +/-1)? And also, if this is independent of number of samples and input-dimension, then what is it dependent on?

Comment: It's everything explained. D is some a-priori known constant defined by the norm on the samples (it's metric describing the samples). y is also a constant, but it's unknown a-priori as we need to learn it. y is not the target, it's the final margin of the solution. So it's dependent on input-statistics (the norm bounding D) and the margin of the final classifier.

Comment: Oh sorry for my ignorance, but what does a-priori mean? I have little math background. Would it be possible for you to link me to an example site which shows a dataset and calculates the number of iterations needed for PLA. Thanks.

Comment: In this case a-priori and a-posteriori (wiki helps) are just used to distinguish the time when we know something. D is known when we iterate one time over all samples (not doing learning); the marging though is not known. So no, without learning, you can only use some upper bound on the marging to estimate the upper-bound of iterations as the knowledge of the marging is obtained during learning.

Comment: Is it possible to detect divergence of perceptron during learning?